# How can I get the lightning button variant dynamically?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have created the `Map<String,Map<List>String>` in javascript and created another `Map<String,String>`. I want to use the `Map<String,String>` into the same for:each loop of LWC Html

Please find the below code for more understanding

**JS Code**

```
this.Data.Attribute.forEach(newData=>{
            
            let attribute = newData;
            let label = attribute.AttributeLabel;
            let value = attribute.ProductAttributeLabel;
            let defualtValue = attribute.AttributeDefaultValue;
            let mapbrandkeyValue = label+'-'+defualtValue; //second map<String,String>
            
            console.log(mapbrandkeyValue);
            mapKeyBrand.set(mapbrandkeyValue,'brand');

            if(mapAttData.has(label)){
                let values = mapAttData.get(label);
                values.push(value);
                mapAttData.set(label,values);

            }else{
                //console.log('Values',value[]);
                let values = [value];
                mapAttData.set(label, values);
            }
        })
       
        console.log('mapKeyBrand',mapKeyBrand);
        mapAttData.forEach((values, label) => {
            this.structuredData.push({ label: label, values: values });
        });

        mapKeyBrand.forEach((value, key) => {
            this.brandData.push({ key: key, value: value });
        });
```

**HTML Code**


**{attLabel.label}**

```
            <lightning-button-group key={attLabel}> 
                <template for:each={attLabel.values} for:item="attValue">
                    <td key={attValue}>/
                            <lightning-button label={attValue} variant="neutral"><!- - I want to add the key in variant so that i Can get the variant dynamically--></lightning-button></td>
                </template>
            </lightning-button-group> 
        
            </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would side-step the problem and have one map holding an object of both values:

```
values.push({label, variant});
```

and then in the LWC:

```
<lightning-button label={attValue.label} variant={attValue.variant}>
```

Comment: Hi Keith C, I want to show the data as well with the variant and that data is like label and value

Comment: My. point is to have one map key that maps to an object with 2 (or more values) so you are only iterating over one collection.

Comment: So you mean that it should be Map<String,Map<String,List<String>>>

Comment: It would be `Map<String, Map<List<Map<String, String>>>` so the list holds an object that in turn holds the two values.